# Hide Edit and delete button for each group Odoo 12

Tags: xml, security, odoo, odoo-12

I want to hide the edit, create and delete button based on the user group. You can edit ir.model.access.csv
I tried all the roads but did not succeed:

n°1 :

```
hr.access_hr_department_user, hr.department.user, model_hr_Department, hr.group_hr_user, 1,0,0,0
```

n°2:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_hr_department_form_groups_section">
    <field name="name">edit_button</field>
    <field name="model">hr.department</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_department_form"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('security_groups.group_supervisor_department') )]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/form" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="create">false</attribute>
            <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Solution N°2 hide button for all groups

n°3:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_hr_department_form_groups_section">
    <field name="name">edit_button</field>
    <field name="model">hr.department</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_department_form"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('security_groups.group_supervisor_department') )]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form create= 'false' editable ='false' >

        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the No. 1.

To make it work:

- Check that you are importing the ir.model.access.csv in the **__manifest__.py** (**__openerp__.py**)
- Check that your not using the admin user, that user is not affected
  by the access rules.

If it doesn't work, please share the ir.model.access.csv

Comment: Thank you for helping me, when I work on the server appears to the fullest, I did not understand what the problem in local,  It can be in the Odoo 12 version is not the same commit ?